# the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ in $\int f{{\left({x}\right)}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

It seems the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ in  $$\int f{{\left({x}\right)}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}$$ is multiplication, since I find many similar examples like this
[image]
Anyone can explain why the relationship between $f(x)$ and $dx$ in  $\int f{{\left({x}\right)}}{\left.{d}{x}\right.}$ is multiplication? what does $dx$ mean here ?

Comment: For calculus: In the formal expression $\int f(x){\rm d}x$ it's really just a *label* telling us to integrate the function $f(x)$ with respect to the variable $x$. Due to the way our notation for derivatives is we can usually treat it as a number that is multiplied with $f(x)$ which is very convenient when we perform substitutions.

Comment: @Winther but why the relationship is multiplication ?

Comment: If you are looking for an intuitive reason then the Riemann integral $\int f(x){\rm d}x \sim \sum f(x_k)\Delta x_k$ makes this explicit. That we can *treat it* as number that is multiplied by $f(x)$ follows from the substitution theorem where $\int f(g(x)) g'(x){\rm d}x = \left.\int f(u){\rm d}u\right|_{u=g(x)}$ so when making a subs. $u = g(x)$ then writing $\frac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$ as $du = g'(x)dx$ gives us the right result even though $du=g'(x)dx$ is not a sensible thing to write in calculus (a derivative is not a fraction).

Answer (score 1):

The integral in its Riemann-interpretation is the sum of infinitely narrow rectangles with the infinitesimal width $dx$ and height $f(x)$. Their "area" is just $f(x)*dx$.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is heavily criticized in this book at P125 in Part "leibnitz's notation for the Integral " https://books.google.ca/books?id=vOMlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&dq=introduction+to+calculus+and+analysis&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20calculus%20and%20analysis&f=false